# Headers are not read in IBM MQ

Tags: java, ibm-mq, mq

Im trying to put a message with some headers to a topic and get them using the java client [1]. However, I am able to successfully put the message with headers, but unable to get the headers from the message. Here is the code I'm trying.

**Put to Topic**

```java
MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
MQDLH mqdlh = new MQDLH();
mqdlh.setDestQName("DEV.QUEUE.1");
mqdlh.setIntValue("Reason", 10);

MQTM mqtm = new MQTM();
mqtm.setApplId("TestAppId");
mqtm.setProcessName("TestProcessName");

MQHeaderList headerList = new MQHeaderList();
headerList.add(mqdlh);
headerList.add(mqtm);
headerList.write(message);

MQPropertyDescriptor d = new MQPropertyDescriptor();
d.version = MQPD_USER_CONTEXT;
message.writeString("Your message payload");
topic.put(message);
```

**Get from Topic**

```java
MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
gmo.options = MQGMO_WAIT;
gmo.waitInterval = MQConstants.MQWI_UNLIMITED;
topic.get(msg, gmo);

MQHeaderIterator iterator = new MQHeaderIterator(msg);

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          MQHeader header = iterator.nextHeader();
          System.out.println(header);
}
```

The iterator always returns an empty result here. However, if I try to read headers one by one as follows, I'm able to successfully get them.

```java
MQDLH dlh = new MQDLH();
dlh.read(msg);
System.out.println(new String(dlh.getDestQName()));
System.out.println((dlh.getValue("Reason")));
```

I'm unable to understand the issue here and any help regarding this is much appreciated. Is there any configuration that I should give to make this work?

*Edit*

Since I couldn't make above format work, I'm manually reading the headers and going through all the available types. Something like below.

```java
switch (type) {
            case MQRFH2: {
                MQRFH2 mqrfh2 = new MQRFH2();
                try {
                    mqrfh2.read(msg);
                    headers.add(getBHeaderFromMQRFH2(runtime, mqrfh2));
                    break;
                } catch (MQDataException e) {
                    msg.seek(dataOffset);
                }
            }
            /*-fallthrough*/
            case MQDLH: {
                MQDLH dlh = new MQDLH();
                try {
                    // Only MQRFH2 headers is supported at the moment. Other headers are read here
                    // to move the cursor to the payload value.
                    dlh.read(msg);
                    break;
                } catch (MQDataException e) {
                    msg.seek(dataOffset);
                }
            }
            .......
            .......
            .......
}
```

This workaround is not perfect. But is there any other workaround available?

[1] https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient/9.3.4.0

Comment: Unfortunately, the `MQHeaderIterator` does not support all MQ headers, see [Handling IBM MQ message headers with IBM MQ classes for Java](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=applications-handling-mq-message-headers-mq-classes-java).

Comment: Yes. But a header like `MQRFH2` is supported right? So I should be able to read it from the iterator. But I am unable to read that single type of header as well.

Comment: Does the processing enter the while loop. IE. does `hasNext` return true at least once?

Comment: @chughts nope
It's always false. I'm wondering whether I need to add some configuration value when creating the TOPIC or QM.

Comment: I saw this option - `PROPCTL` [1]. But I don't know where to set it.

[1] https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=options-propctl-queue-mqgmo

Answer (score 1):

I am so confused why you are trying to do what you are doing.

Why in the world would you ever create a message with two embedded structures:

- Dead Letter Header (MQDLH)
- Trigger Monitor (MQTM)

That means your messages would look like:

```
{MQDLH}{MQTM}{message_payload}
```

Then, push that message to a topic. Why?? It is the strangest thing I ever seen.

And you add your workaround that has MQRFH2 followed by MQDLH embedded structures
That means your messages would look like:

```
{MQRFH2}{MQTM}{message_payload}
```

In case you don't know, a JMS message is stored by MQ as an MQRFH2 message. So, if you simply put a JMS message to the topic, it will automatically have the embedded MQRFH2 structure.
i.e. JMS message internally looks like this:

```
{MQRFH2}{message_payload}
```

Years ago, I gave up trying to get the MQHeaderIterator class to work because it was very poorly implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Roger. I'm not exactly familiar with IBM MQ and my idea was that we can send different types of headers in one single message. That's why I tried this way. What I'm trying to do is, create a wrapper around the IBM MQ java client and provide a way for users to read the headers without using the `HeaderIterator` or `HeaderList`. Looks like `MQHeaderIterator` won't work for me :(

Comment: I think you are making a work project where one is not required. Forget about MQTM & MQDLH structures because applications don't need it. For MQRFH2 structure, just treat the message as a JMS message & life will be good. No wrapper is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment in response to a request made in a comment, but it wouldn't fit it into a comment. It does not answer the original question, just a follow up.

You can use `runmqsc` to check and to update the `PROPCTL` option for a queue. You need to be an administrator, but you can run `runmqsc` remotely. You will need the redistributable client installed - https://developer.ibm.com/articles/mq-downloads/

If you are running MQ in a docker image locally on your machine, then you can run:

```
export MQSERVER=DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN/TCP/localhost(1414)

runmqsc -c -u admin QM1
```

If your queue manager is running elsewhere then you will most likely need a ccdt to connect.

```
unset MQSERVER
export MQCCDTURL=<path-to-ccdt-file>
export MQSSLKEYR=<full-path-to-keydb-file> 

runmqsc -c -u <admin user id> -w 60 QM1
```

Once runmqsc is running you can issue MQSC commands. You can check the queue options by running

```
display queue(DEV.QUEUE.1)
```

If you see `PROPCTL(NONE)` then the headers will not be sent, unless

> If the application calls MQCRTMH to create a message handle, it must
> query the message properties using MQINQMP. Name-value pairs that are
> not message properties remain in the MQRFH2, which is stripped of any
> message properties. If the application does not create a message
> handle, all the message properties are removed from the MQRFH2.
> Name-value pairs in the MQRFH2 headers remain in the message.

You can set PROPCTL by running

```
ALTER QLOCAL(DEV.QUEUE.1) PROPCTL(COMPAT)
```

`COMPAT` is the default setting. If its not set to COMPAT, then an admin has deliberately changed it.

Comment: PROPTL only affects MQRFH2 headers - that is message properties. Why do you think that this will impact OP? He says the headers are on the message if he accesses them individually. Why would PROPCTL have an impact on an iterator?

Comment: @MoragHughson If PROPCTL only relates to MQRFH2 headers, at least other headers should be available right?

For the moment, what I am doing is manually trying to read the header and go through all the header types. Something like my latest edit on the above question. Can this solution go wrong?

Comment: @dilanSachi - I a not familiar enough with Java iterators to know why they don't work. If I were writing an application like yours in my chosen language then what you have done is what I would have to do anyway.

Comment: In this answer, your final statement is contradictory. If the default is `COMPAT` (which it is) then it will be already set to `COMPAT` and an admin has not deliberately change it, it was set by default. Are you missing the word "not" somewhere in there?

Comment: corrected the typo.